# Dynamic Matrix Multiplication with Pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm a beginner with Thread Programming and C in general and I'm trying to figure out how to do a simple Matrix Multiplication with Pthreads. I want to create a thread for every column and put the results in a Result Matrix. I'm trying to do it dynamicly, which means the user is allowed to use an input as a size to create two n x n matrices.

My code right now, excluding filling the matrix and reading the size n is the following:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
int line, col, size;
double (*MA)[];
double (*MB)[];
double (*MC)[];
} Matrix;


void *multiply(void *arg) {
Matrix* work = (Matrix*) arg;
int s, z;
s = work->col;
z = work->line;
 work->MC[0][0] = 0.0.//can't use MC, MB, MA here!!
return 0;
}

int main() {
Matrix* m;
//read size and set it to int size (miissing here, does work)

double MA[size][size], MB[size][size], MC[size][size];
int i, j;
//filling the matrices (missing here, does work)

pthread_t threads[size];

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    m = malloc(sizeof(Matrix*));
    m->size = size;
    m->col = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multiply, m);

}

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
return 0;

}
```

The problem is, that I cant use neither MA, MB nor NC(:= the result) in the multiply method with something like its shown in the code.
I just get the error "invalid use of array with unspecific bounds" even though I declared all three of them in the main method.

Do I understand anything wrong here or how can I fix that? I tried to adapt a example of my lecture where a thread for every element will be created.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can you use MC in multiply if you ever alloc it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The Problem is I can't use it in multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about the error:

```
 work->MC[0][0] = 0.0.//can't use MC, MB, MA here!!
```

`MC` was declared as `double (*MC)[]` and you try to use it as a two dimensional array like you had declared it `double MC[N]{M]`. You can use a two (or more) dimensional array like you did if and only if the first dimension was fixed or if you alloc it row by row.

So your program could be:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
    int line, col, size;
    double MA[][];
    double MB[][];
    double MC[][];
} Matrix;

void *multiply(void *arg) {
    Matrix* work = (Matrix*) arg;
    int s, z;
    s = work->col;
    z = work->line;
    work->MC[0][0] = 0.0
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Matrix* m;
    //read size and set it to int size (miissing here, does work)

    double MA[][], MB[][], MC[][];
    int i, j;
    pthread_t threads[size];

    MA = (double **) malloc(size * sizeof(double *));
    MB = (double **) malloc(size * sizeof(double *));
    MC = (double **) malloc(size * sizeof(double *));
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
        MA[i] = (double *) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
        MB[i] = (double *) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
        MC[i] = (double *) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        m = malloc(sizeof(Matrix*));
        m->MA = MA;
        m->MB = MB;
        m->MC = MC;
        m->size = size;
        m->col = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, multiply, m);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But you must TAKE CARE that the thread can access to the data concurrently and so you should use some locks if different threads can use and change same values.

Comment: Alright,thanks, but I can't define it two dimensional in the struct because I don't know the size of them. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I see where the problem was, but what is "s" in e.g. "s->size"?

Comment: @rehne93 nothing... just a TYPO

Comment: @rehne93 Now it should be OK

Comment: That works, thank you. But I still can't use them in the multiply method.., still the same error if I try to write/print an value.

Comment: @rehne93 I forget to change the struct definition ... I'm doing right now